# Doctrine child properties lazy loading

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I am trying to retrieve entities from database using lazy loading.

Considering the following structure :

User.php

```
class User
{
    private id;
    private groups;
}
```

Group.php

```
class Group
{
    private id;
    private users;
}
```

With a manyToMany relation between both entities.

When I call find() on my UserRepository, I got as a result a User object with nested Group objects in groups property.

I would like to get an array containing the groups ids in the groups property, instead of a Group collection.

I tried to use fetch="EXTRA_LAZY" on the child entities but that had no effect.

Some help to achieve this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get only list of ID's from ManyToMany with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400194/get-only-list-of-ids-from-manytomany-with-doctrine)

Comment: That lead me to the solution, thank you.